# How to handle checkbox using TestComplete?

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

I am automating Java webAplication using Testcomplete12.X on Edge browser.

How to verify whether the checkbox is checked or unChecked? I have tried below ways but it is not working.

```
Checkbox.ClickButton();

 if(Checkbox.wState==cbChecked)
 {

 Log.Message("checked");
 }
 else
 {

 Log.Message("unChecked");
 }
```

Smartbear support link: https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-objects/specific-tasks/standard/check-box/determining-state.html

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Java webApplication"? Is it a Java applet, JSP app or an HTML page built with JavaScript? Can you also post here the HTML code of the check box?

Comment: Thnaks for the response buddy,
I have resolved the issue. the web application is using images as checkboxes. i have handled it by giving if else condition.


Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to log the value of Checkbox.wState?
Whenever I stuck with something in TC I log( or create an item in the watch list).